# ElasticSearch : Handling apostrophe using ngram analyzer

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, n-gram

I want to be able to be able to search for content that can contain apostrophes, using the ngram analyzer :

I created an index and mapped my content to the analyzer I defined :

```
async function createIndex() {
    var settings = {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
                "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
                ]
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 2,
              "max_gram": 10,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }

    return await client.indices.create({
        index: 'books',
        body: {
            settings: settings
        }
    });
}
```

However, when I search for something like "arc'hant", it searches in reality for "arc" and "hant" instead of one word, so it returns matches that I don't want to return.

This is the search request I do :

```
router.get('/autocomplete', function(req, res, next) {
    var content = req.query.term;
    content = content.toLowerCase();

    client.search({
      index: 'books',
      type: 'books',
      body:{
        "query": {
          "query_string" : {
            "fields" : [
               "name^5",
               "content"
            ],
            "query" : content,
            "default_operator" : "AND"
          }
        }
      }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        res.send(resp);
    }, function (err) {
        res.send(formatError(err));
    });

});
```

What would be the way to handle that?

Comment: any clue? I don't know what I should do to handle that..

Answer (score 0):

Adding "punctuation" in the `token_chars` made it work!

Comment: it didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245897/elasticsearch-match-query-does-not-match-a-document-with-apostrophe?noredirect=1&lq=1